# Out of Memory exception when reading Workbook.VBProject.References

Tags: vb.net, excel-2013

We have an application written in VB.NET that will merge two XLSM workbooks into a singe XLSM workbook.
Approach is that we open both source and target workbooks and get each sheet of the source workbook and insert it into the target workbook. This is done for all the workbooks that are needed to be merged into the target workbook. 
After the merging is done we programatically add reference of our custom add-in (.XLA) to the target workbook. 
All goes well till we try to insert a reference of our custom addin (.XLA). To add the addin we first check whether the addin is already available in the target workbook (part of a business rule). So, we iterate through each reference and compare the name against our add-in name. At the point where we try to get the references of the excel it throws out of memory exception, this happens even if we do not have our add in reference and just out of the box Excel reference whose count is only 4. 
I receive the exception at the below point in our code. 
Workbook.VBProject.References
This works fine if we have .xls (93-2007) format of both source and target workbooks and also if the source XLSM workbook doesn't contain any macro.
Any pointers what could be the issue?
P.S - We use late binding for all excel manipulations in the above application.

```
Public Function CopySheets(ByVal ExcelWorkbooks As Object, ByVal SourceTemplatePath As String, ByVal TargetTemplatePath As String, ByVal CopyAfter As Boolean, ByVal DeleteOriginalSheets As Boolean) As Integer

    Dim SheetsToBeCopied As Integer = 0
    Dim SourceExcelWorkbook As Object = Nothing
    Dim TargetExcelWorkbook As Object = Nothing
    Dim CopyWorkSheet As Object = Nothing
    Dim SheetBefore As Object = Nothing

    Try

        SourceExcelWorkbook = ExcelWorkbooks.Open(SourceTemplatePath)
        TargetExcelWorkbook = ExcelWorkbooks.Open(TargetTemplatePath)

        Dim lintSheetsToBeCopiedCount As Integer = SourceExcelWorkbook.worksheets.count
        SheetsToBeCopied = lintSheetsToBeCopiedCount
        If CopyAfter = False Then

            While lintSheetsToBeCopiedCount > 0
                SheetBefore = TargetExcelWorkbook.worksheets.item(1)
                CopyWorkSheet = SourceExcelWorkbook.worksheets.item(lintSheetsToBeCopiedCount)
                CopyWorkSheet.move(Before:=SheetBefore)
                lintSheetsToBeCopiedCount = lintSheetsToBeCopiedCount - 1
                TargetExcelWorkbook.save()
            End While

        Else
            Dim lintOriginalSheetCount As Integer = TargetExcelWorkbook.worksheets.count
            Dim lintSheetCount As Integer = lintOriginalSheetCount
            While lintSheetsToBeCopiedCount > 0

                Dim lobjAfterSheet As Object = TargetExcelWorkbook.worksheets.item(lintSheetCount)
                CopyWorkSheet = SourceExcelWorkbook.worksheets.item(1)
                CopyWorkSheet.Move(After:=lobjAfterSheet)
                lintSheetCount = lintSheetCount + 1
                TargetExcelWorkbook.save()
                lintSheetsToBeCopiedCount = lintSheetsToBeCopiedCount - 1

            End While

            TargetExcelWorkbook.save()

            If DeleteOriginalSheets = True Then
                For lintIndex As Integer = 1 To lintOriginalSheetCount
                    TargetExcelWorkbook.worksheets.item(1).delete()
                Next
            End If
        End If

        TargetExcelWorkbook.save()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    Finally


        If Not CopyWorkSheet Is Nothing Then
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(CopyWorkSheet)
            CopyWorkSheet = Nothing
        End If

        If SheetBefore IsNot Nothing Then
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(SheetBefore)
            SheetBefore = Nothing
        End If

        If Not SourceExcelWorkbook Is Nothing Then
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(SourceExcelWorkbook)
            SourceExcelWorkbook = Nothing
        End If

        If Not TargetExcelWorkbook Is Nothing Then
            Try
                TargetExcelWorkbook.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
            Catch ex As Exception
                'ignore
            End Try
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(TargetExcelWorkbook)
            SourceExcelWorkbook = Nothing
        End If
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
    Return SheetsToBeCopied
End Function
```

Comment: Can you provide some code

Comment: @Bauss -  i have edited the post to include the sample code. Can you help me out here.

Comment: Any body who can help me out here?